# Digium card is not getting the Green lights

Tags: asterisk

I have added and conigured the digium card in Lenny. 
I have used the dahdi also.
While booting the machine my card gets red alarm. Once I got the login screen I didn't get any alarm in my card. Please update wheather it is card problem or driver problem.

It is urgent Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your card has a problem, your card is ready as soon as dahdi kernel modules are loaded. Maybe look at your boot process and see if dahdi start at the right moment